# Mysql CREATE statment are really slow (Mac OS X / Macport install)

Tags: mysql, macports

I recently noticed that recreating the database for the web application I am working on is taking a lot of time. I had just reinstalled Mysql from Macport...

I am getting really lousy performances, for example :

0.293437004089 seconds for

```
CREATE TABLE blockip ( 
id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
username VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
time INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (id) ) 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci TYPE=MyISAM;
```

On another machine, nearby I get 0.0016529560089111 seconds for the same query.

The trouble seems to be somewhat related to the disk : disk usage goes really high when I start creating the 70 tables in my database.

Any ideas where to start for a clue ?

Comment: this question would be better suited on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I added the same question over there. Thanks for the tip... We'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this myself and found the issue is to do with a file function that is available on  OS X but not other operating systems that MySQL chooses to use as it is safer. Check out the last 3 comments on this bug report: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=56550.

It details adding a directive to your my.cnf file that will disable using the different function and dramatically speeds up all file based actions in MySQL on OS X. So, you can fix this quickly by adding the following to your `my.cnf` file in the `[mysqld]` block. It’s probably best not to do this in production, but who actually uses OS X as a production web server anyway?

```
skip-sync-frm=OFF
```

I saw my unit test schema creation come down from 16 seconds to 5 making it a clear winner for me.

Comment: Sorry to state the obvious, but make sure you restart your mysql daemon after changing the my.cnf file for it to work :)